# Error al agregar sentencia if en un forEach()

Tags: java

tengo una funcion que guarda una lista en una base de datos postgresql, y necesito filtrar los valores nulos y "0" por lo cual hice un if, el cual se me ejecuta bien en su primera iteracion en el forEach, pero luego me genera un javaNullPointerException y no comprendo, el por que se me genera este error.
muchas gracias por la ayuda de ante mano.

```
 @Override
public void savePosicion(List<MovilTO> obj) {
    try(SqlSession session = new Conexion().getSessionLocal()){
        session.delete("PosicionLocal.truncatePosition");
        obj.forEach((item) -> {
            if((item.getLongitud() !=0 || item.getLongitud() !=null) & (item.getLatitud() !=0 || item.getLatitud() !=null)){
                session.insert("PosicionLocal.savePosicion",item);
            }
        });
       session.commit();
       session.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error insertar posicion"+ e);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como recomendación, siempre checkea primero el si es nulo antes que si es = 0. También estaría bien que pusieses la traza completa del error, una captura no ayuda a ver la traza.

Comment: Que objeto o al llamar a que metodo , te da ese null pointer?

Comment: tal cual como me dices, realice ese cambio pero igual, al momento de validar = 0 me generaba error muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

```
al ingresar en el if y relizar la validacion si la variable venia null, la validacion distinto a "0"no podia cumplirse y daba error.
```

entonces realice lo siguiente:

```
 public void savePosicion(List<MovilTO> obj) {
    try(SqlSession session = new Conexion().getSessionLocal()){
        session.delete("PosicionLocal.truncatePosition");
        obj.forEach((item) -> {
            if(( item.getLongitud() !=null ) & (item.getLatitud() !=null )){
                if(item.getLongitud() !=0 & item.getLatitud() !=0 ){
                    session.insert("PosicionLocal.savePosicion",item);
                }
            }
        });
       session.commit();
       session.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error insertar posicion"+ e);
    }
}
```